# Using v8 handle from a thread fails

Tags: c++, node.js, v8

From what I understand v8 supports multi-threading as long as v8::Locker is used in functions accessed by threads.

However in the following sample I can't use the callback from a thread:

```
static Persistent<v8::Function> cb;
void PostMessage(){
  Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
  v8::Locker locker(isolate);
  HandleScope scope(isolate);

  const unsigned argc = 1;
  Local<Value> argv[argc] = { String::NewFromUtf8(isolate, "test") };

  Local<v8::Function> PostMessageCb = Local<v8::Function>::New(isolate, cb);
  (PostMessageCb)->Call(isolate->GetCurrentContext()->Global(), argc, argv);
}

void SetupCallback(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
    Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();
    v8::Locker locker(isolate);
    HandleScope scope(isolate);
    Local<v8::Function> local_cb = Local<v8::Function>::Cast(args[0]);
    cb.Reset(isolate, local_cb);
}

void UseCallback(const FunctionCallbackInfo<Value>& args) {
    //PostMessage(); <- that works
    std::thread t(PostMessage); // <- that doesn't
    t.join();
}
```

Am I using v8::Locker incorrectly?

EDIT: Found a problem with my code. Instead of

```
(PostMessageCb)->Call(isolate->GetCurrentContext()->Global(), argc, argv);
```

Get creation context:

```
(PostMessageCb)->Call(PostMessageCb->CreationContext()->Global(), argc, argv);
```

Comment: _"I can't use the callback from a thread"_ - We're not mind readers, you have to tell us why you can't use it and/or what is failing and where.

Comment: Segmentation fault happens at the last line of the PostMessage function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From my experience with trying to use Lockers and such, the only real way to do this is to just use [`uv_async`](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/295882ed3238d6bfda61f5a91e1b43eb210fc485/include/uv.h#L1178-L1200) from the other thread to send messages to the main thread where you execute the callback function. [The tests for `uv_async`](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/4ba03ddd569bdd361b1498d5f19ec0075db01500/test/test-async.c) may help with usage.

Comment: Ah thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Didn't realize that libuv can use the node.js default loop. This intro to libuv was really helpful http://nikhilm.github.io/uvbook/basics.html